# General solution of partial differential equations.

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

Find the general solution of the given differential equation

$$ \frac{y^2}{2}-2ye^t+(y-e^t)\frac{dy}{dt}=0$$

So here is my process:

Let:

$$\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial t}=\frac{y^2}{2}-2ye^t$$

where:

$$ \phi(y,t)=\frac{y^2}{2}t-2ye^t+h(y)$$
and let :

$$\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial y}=y-e^t$$

where: 
$$ \phi(y,t)=\frac{y^2}{2}-ye^t+k(t)$$

Now I need to find k(t) and h(y) to make the two $\phi(y,t)$ equal. so this is where i'm stuck, if anyone can help, it be most appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:**
$$ \frac{y^2}{2}-2ye^t+(y-e^t)\frac{dy}{dt}=0$$
$$ \frac{y^2}{2}-ye^t+\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{y^2}{2}-ye^t\right)=0$$
Define $z:=\frac{y^2}{2}-ye^t$, hence
$$z+\frac{dz}{dt}=0\qquad z(t)=z_{0}e^{-t}$$

Comment: hmm. I understand the first two steps, you just integrate and then you substitute for z. What I don't understand is the last line.

Comment: In the last line I simply solved the separable equation for z $$\frac{dz}{z}=-dt\qquad \log\left|\frac{z}{\tilde{z}}\right|=-(t-\tilde{t})$$ where $\tilde{z}$ and $\tilde{t}$ are constants. The result is obtained defining $z_0:=\tilde{z}e^{\tilde{t}}$. At this point to get you solution you just need to solve a quadratic equation in $y$.

Comment: alright. thanks!